# Darkening Sprites at distance Java

Tags: java, image, game-engine, lighting, 2.5d

I have written a fully functional first-person-shooter (2.5D styled), though I'd like for sprites to be darkened at a distance from the camera(inverse-square function).

I've got the math down, but with little experience using BufferedImages, I do not know how to go about lowering pixel values (with alpha) or simply tinting them black.

Note: I am also buffering to a canvas(Image) with a Graphics2D

All insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To darken a bufferedimage, you can just use a rescaleop. This snippet will darken it by 20%.

```
float factor = .8f; 
RescaleOp op = new RescaleOp(factor, 0, null);
image= op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```